# How in immutable js i can each in map method?

Tags: reactjs, reactjs-flux, redux, immutable.js

How:

```
    let type = [ "categories", "people", "organization"];
    let tab = filterCache.map((name) =>
        type.each((i) =>
            <Tab>{name[i]} ({1})</Tab>
        )
    );
```

This return error : Unexpected token input

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about the folllowing snippet?

```
let tab = filterCache.map((name) =>
    return type.each((i) => {
        (<Tab>{name[i]} ({1})</Tab>)
    });
);
```

Independently of the library stack you are using the function applied to`map`requires a `return`statement.